# How many JDBC query quests will be issued when I invoke getXX() on every element in lazy-fetch collection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have a lazy-fetch `List` of `Member`:

```
@OneToMany
    List<Member> getMemberList() {
        return this.memberList;
    }
```

If I do the following stuff in an active JPA session:

```
 List<Member> mList = obj.getMemberList();
    for (Member m : mList) {
        m.getName();
    }
```

I know the common practice for this operation is invoke `mList.size()` method. I'm just wondering that how many queries will be issued when I iterate the collection and call `getXX()` method on each of the element? I'm using Hibernate as JPA's provider.

Comment: depends on the JPA implementation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One query.

Unless the getName() method is also lazy.... in which case 'N+1' queries.

But, since you're asking about the memberList, it's 1.  A single lazy load of the list (well, up to fetch limit / batch sizes).  The size() method is not magical.  Regular usage, such as iteration, will trigger the "faulting" of the lazy-loading reference proxy and get the data.